# Phonegap Build cli-6.5.0 won't load Google Drive

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-drive-api, phonegap

I have an app built for iOS that accesses Google Drive using the Javascript client.  This has been working okay for a couple of years now but the old version was using Phonegap build cli-5.4.1 which, due to its imminent deprecation, I have upgraded to cli-6.5.0.  With the new version the app will no longer load the Drive API.

I have a central Google Drive account and the app accesses a web server that authenticates to that account, obtains a refresh token and then delivers that token back to my app.  The app then loads the client API using this code:

```
var gapiClient = document.createElement('script');
gapiClient.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js';
```

I then pass it the refresh token obtained from the web server:

```
gapi.auth.setToken(token)
```

and finally, load the drive API:

```
gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', callback);
```

It is this last step that is failing, with the callback function not being called and the app then just hangs.

In my config.xml I have the following access origin statements:

```
<access origin="https://*.google.com" />
<access origin="https://*.googleapis.com" />
```

Can anyone please advise what has changed with this latest version and, hopefully, advise what needs to be done to remedy.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem.  With the latest iOS version (4.3.1) in Phonegap you also have to specify in the config,xml a new command,

```
<allow-navigaton href="https://*.google.com" />
```